# StandardForm to Infix form conversion is working but Infix to StandardForm not working. Why?

Tags: conversion, input-forms

I have a function `f1` with three inputs: `x1`,`y1`,`z1`. I have written this in standard form as

```
f1[x1, y1, z1]
```

I wanted to convert to `Infix` form so I did

```
Infix[f1[x1, y1, z1]]
```

Now I wanted to convert it back to `StandardForm` so I did

```
StandardForm[Infix[f1[x1, y1, z1]]]
```

It is not returning back this

```
 f1[x1, y1, 1z]
```

Instead, it is giving me this

```
   x1~f1~y1~f1~z1
```

I'm expecting `StandarForm` and `Infix` functions need to be kind of inverse of each other.

```
StandardForm[Infix[
   StandardForm[Infix[
     f1[x1, y1, z1]]]]]
```

I thought that the output of the above should be

```
 f1[x1, y1, z1]
```

But it is not. Why? What concept I'm missing here?

Comment: `Infix[f[x,y,z]]; StandardForm[%]` works.

Comment: It is not working in 11.0 version

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `Infix` isn't a function: it just a formatting wrapper which affects printing, but not evaluation (like `NumberForm`, `InputForm` etc.):

```
Infix[f1[x1, y1, z1]]
```

> x1 ~f1~ y1 ~f1~ z1

```
% // FullForm
```

> ```
> Infix[f1[x1, y1, z1]]
> ```

Likewize `StandardForm` is also just a wrapper with the only difference that it is stripped off if the output is printed:

```
sf = StandardForm[f1[x1, y1, z1]]
```

> ```
> f1[x1, y1, z1]
> ```

```
% // FullForm
sf // FullForm
```

> ```
> f1[x1, y1, z1]
> StandardForm[f1[x1, y1, z1]]
> ```

Secondly, the generated infix form is't equivalent to the original expression as one can easily see by copying it and evaluating:

```
x1 ~f1~ y1 ~f1~ z1
```

> ```
> f1[f1[x1, y1], z1]
> ```

But since this infix form is just a *display form* and the Kernel still keeps the original expression simply wrapped with `Infix`, you can easily get it back in the `StandardForm` just by replacing the `Head` by `StandardForm`:

```
StandardForm @@ Infix[f1[x1, y1, z1]]
```

> ```
> f1[x1, y1, z1]
> ```

... or just by removing the `Infix` `Head`:

```
Infix[f1[x1, y1, z1]]
% // First
```

> x1 ~f1~ y1 ~f1~ z1
>
> ```
> f1[x1, y1, z1]
> ```